# KineticJs validating jigsaw pieces?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, kineticjs, puzzle

does anybody know how could I validate my jigsaw pieces back into the original place after being scrambled? and show that I have completed the puzzle? Currrently i am using kineticJs library. Thanks :)

```
function jigsaw(){
    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "kidwallpaper.jpg";
    imageObj.onload = function(){
        drawImage(this);
    }
 }
```

P.S : My jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vFez6/21/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to define a circle where each piece connects to another piece.

For example, assume your puzzle has just 2 pieces -- a top piece and a bottom piece.

This illustration shows a red circle on the top piece and a gold circle on the bottom piece.

[image]

When the connection circles exactly overlap then pieces are exactly connected.

[image]

Of course you probably want to give your players a margin-of-error so they don't need to **exactly** overlap the circles.  Perhaps if the 2 circles overlap at all then it's "good enough" to be called solved.

If you have defined the x,y,radius of the 2 circles then you can tell if they overlap at all like this:

```
var dx = circle2.x - circle1.x;
var dy = circle2.y - circle1.y;
var isSolved = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) <= circle.radius*2;
```

I see that you are rotating your pieces.  This means that you must also test that the rotation angle of the 2 pieces are the same for them to be connected.

Naturally you wouldn't actually draw the circles -- they are just here for illustration.

Comment: Sorry, i dont quite get it, could you do some real example that i can try or edit abit of mine code to show me? thanks so much :)

Comment: "I don't quite get it" is a bit vague.  What are you having problems with?

Comment: Time does not permit.   The key is to create imaginary circles where piece#1 properly connects to piece#2. For example, assume piece#1's tab will fit properly into piece#2's slot. Create an imaginary circle over piece#1's tab and another circle over piece#2's slot. Then test if those 2 circles intersect using the code snippet in my answer.  If yes, then that tab-slot connection is "solved".  Cheers!